# Unable to get description text from google search using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the below code which extracts url and title of the google search page. However I am unable to extract the description.
I tried using `.find` with div and class but I get back empty list or `None`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

base = "https://www.google.de"
link = "https://www.google.de/search?q={}"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

def grab_content(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for container in soup.select("[class='g'] a[href^='http'][data-ved]:has(h3)"):
        post_title = container.select_one("h3").get_text(strip=True)
        post_description = container.select_one("div", {"class": "VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc lEBKkf"}).get_text()    
        post_link = container.get('href')
        yield post_title,post_link,post_description

    next_page = soup.select_one("a[href][id='pnnext']")
    if next_page:
        next_page_link = urljoin(base,next_page.get("href"))
        yield from grab_content(next_page_link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    search_keyword = "python"
    qualified_link = link.format(search_keyword.replace(" ","+"))
    for item in grab_content(qualified_link):
        print(item)
```

My output:
('Welcome to Python.org', 'https://www.python.org/', 'https://www.python.org')
I am getting title, and url but I am unable to get description which will be something like

> The official home of the Python Programming Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead selecting by `class` that may can change, start from a known part for example the `container` - Select its `parent` and grab `next_siblings` text

```
post_description = container.parent.next_sibling.get_text()
```

#### Output

```
('Welcome to Python.org', 'https://www.python.org/', 'The official home of thePythonProgramming Language.')
...
```